# Odd error in SPSS regression when using dummy variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, spss

I'm entering 15 dummy variables into a regression analysis to control for the 'effect of experiment'.  There are 16 experiments in total, so 15 should be entered.  So I have 16 columns, with a 1 for each participant from experiment 1 in the column "1_dum", and a 1 for each from participant from experiment 2 in the column "2_dum", and so on.

When I run the analysis, I get the following error message, and am not sure why:  column of experiment 1 correspond *"For models with dependent variable XXXX, the following variables are constants or have missing correlations: 7 _dum, 9 _dum, 11 _dum, 12 _dum, 14 _dum. They will be deleted from the analysis."*

I've never seen an error like this before and have ran analyses with dummy variables in this fashion several times. There aren't any missing values in these variables, so I'm not sure why this error is showing up.  Does anyone have any insight into this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do those variables where you get that error have a cardinality > 1?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not legal variable names (because they start with numbers).  Assuming the actual names are different, what are you entering for the values for each dummy that is not 1?  What do you see if  you run Descriptives on the whole set?

Comment: haha I'm an idiot.  It was because the variables entered into the regression were not in the experiments excluded from the regression!   Thank you for your help!